# C++: Help installing FLTK

Tags: windows, user-interface, fltk

I can't seem to figure out how to install FLTK on windows. I tried looking at some things I found online but nothing has worked so far. Would somebody be able to give me a step by step guide on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

0) What did you try?

1) Do you have the Cygwin toolset?

If not, download it.

Extract the files from fltk's tar.gz file using the TAR command. 
Open a command window in the folder for the extracted files. Run:

> > >> bash configure

(I think). When that's done (checking for g++, gcc, and other stuff), run:

> > >> make && make install

I think my install took about 20 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent video tutorial by Greg Ercolano. It explains how to develop a simple FLTK-based application in Microsoft(R) VisualStudio(TM) 7.

Link to the videos: http://seriss.com/people/erco/fltk-videos/

Answer (score 0):

If you have been installed the Code::Blocks (with MingW) and CMake, is quite easy 
compile and install FLTK under Windows.